# Sort is not working from inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I am using a bash script to retrieve data in CSV-style from a database, I **sort** it and put into an external file.

Everything seems to be correct, but **sort** (*sort (GNU coreutils) 8.26*) is not sorting the rows.

That is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mongoexport --type=csv ${QUERY} | /usr/bin/sort > export.csv
```

The content of export.csv remains the same as the original mongoexport-output - it's still unsorted.

The confusing thing is: When I run this command directly from the command line, sort does what it's supposed to do: It sorts the lines.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feels like I spend days on this problem, but I finally figured out what do to. The key to the solution is - as everytime - the debug log. Ofcourse **sort** provides a command line parameter called **--debug**.

This leads this simple and short notice of **sort**, before returning the unsorted data:

> sort: failed to set locale; using simple byte comparison

The solution is to set an environment variable called **LC_ALL** (for some reasons I dont know yet, on Ubuntu I had to use the **LANG** env variable). So that would be the content of my export script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LANG='en_GB.UTF-8'
export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
mongoexport --type=csv ${QUERY} | /usr/bin/sort > export.csv
```

Comment: Using `LC_ALL=C` you'll get much shorter sort times, but possibly incorrect results if there are some multibyte characters in your data that you need to sort on.

Comment: "The solution is to set an environment variable called LC_ALL ...", `man bash`:
`LANG   Used to determine the locale category for any category not specifically selected with a variable starting with LC_.`
`LC_ALL This variable overrides the value of LANG and any other LC_ variable specifying a locale category.` `LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'` _overrides_ `LANG='en_GB.UTF-8'`.

Comment: `sort` is locale aware (`man sort`: `*** WARNING *** The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.`). Good info on locales (`man locale`) is available i.e.: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale